Releasing Agent Based on Process of Different Agent
I am trying to figure out how to release an agent of type BoosterTrailer upon an agent of type Pallet leaving a service block (aptly named service). I have attempted to achieve this by putting the BoosterTrailer population in a waiting block named waitForBooster and then adding the following code to the On exit field of the service block processing pallets:
if(waitForBooster.size()>0){
    BoosterTrailer trailer=waitForBooster.get(0);
    waitForBooster.free(trailer);
}

I thought maybe the issue was having the code being executed by the agent in the service block, so I moved the formula to a function named goTrailer. However, the same issue persists.
When I do this, I get the following errors:

Description:

Type mismatch: cannot convert from Wait<BoosterTrailer> to BoosterTrailer. Location: AgentTransportation/Main/goTrailer - Function



Description:

The method free(BoosterTrailer) is undefined for the type Main._waitForBooster_Population. Location: AgentTransportation/Main/goTrailer - Function`

What is the best way to release an agent from a queue, based on an agent of a different type leaving a service block? I want to do this to simulate a trailer starting a journey based on the start of the journey of the object it's carrying.
Images can be found below:
waitForBooster Properties
Function and Process Flow
Any and all help is greatly appreciated, I've stared at this for quite a bit of time and don't understand why this isn't working.

I assume you wanted to fill up waitForBooster with 100 agents at the beginning, but actually by setting it to Population of agents in the Advanced section, you have a block now that represents 100 different Wait blocks (which will remain empty).
As far as I know, currently it is not possible to insert agents into process flow without either using a Source or an Enter block.
Set waitForBoosters back to Single agent and try something like this:



"As far as I know, currently it is not possible to insert agents into process flow without either using a Source or an Enter block." --> this is correct

Yes, this works! Thank you so much mczandrea and Benjamin

I assume what you are trying is already modeled.
I would suggest you take a look at the Pickup [1] / Dropoff [2] blocks.
On the pickup block, you have agents that are arriving for transportation and another agent that will "pick up" the top agents. By your description, you would use BoosterTrailer to pick up Pallet, and there is an exit representing the combined operation.
Then the Dropoff block would do the reverse operation: get the full BoosterTrailer, and you receive the dropped off items (Pallet) and the empty BoosterTrailer
The block automatically manages the queues for you with no need for  code.
[1] https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/pickup.html#pick-from
[2] https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/dropoff.html
